# Given an unordered array of integers print the median value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given an unordered array of values (zero or positive integers), find the median positive value.

Steps:

Sort array putting 0s at the start
Sort elements after the 0s into numeric order

Run two for loops (i++ and j+2) to find the middle element
Print value

Is this correct?

Notes: 
must do this in place, no copying arrays
array.length functions not allowed

Comment: What do you mean by *i++ and j+2*?

Comment: Surely by sorting you get to know the length of the array and therefore can just go to the middle one

Comment: Two for loops, one that iterates by 1 and one that iterates by 2, so that when the j loop finishes the i loop is in the middle of the array.

Comment: Sorting would be required, yes – but whether it needs two for loops to find “the middle” depend on what specific language you’re using. If it provides the count of array elements and index-based access, then you can have that easier than with two for loops.

Comment: @CBroe *Sorting would be required*, I disagree. Finding the n/2 smallest values is enough to guarantee you found the median (which is the biggest of the smallest n/2 values).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: But we want to ignore the 0 values, so the median value of our positive integers. Is Quickselect still valid?

Comment: Select the (n/2 - z) biggest value, where n is the total amount of numbers and z the amount of zero's.

Comment: @Manu: _“Finding the n/2 smallest values is enough”_ – ok; but would that be quicker than a normal sort?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you can do that in linear time even in a comparison-only model

Comment: Depending on the max size of your integers a modified *RadixSort* or *CountingSort* could outperform *QuickSelect*. For example, if your integers are in the range 0-255 a counting sort would be your best choice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. You just have to be careful to compute correctly the median in arrays of even size. But it's not the best algorithm possible. This algorithm is O(n log n), bounded by the array sorting.

Another option is to implement a [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) with median of medians to achieve an O(n) complexity.

Comment: Just one remark - please note that O(n) is the **average** complexity for quickselect(+1 by the way)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev That is true for naïve quickselect. Quickselect with median of medians pivoting is O(n) worst case.

Comment: interesting - I did not know that.